# EF Core 2 Custom PK name for owned entity not stored in ModelSnapshot

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm currently using the Npgsql provider with EF Core 2.0 in an ASP.NET Core application.

I've converted all table/column/relationship names to snake case in order to fit the Postgres convention and to make it easier to write native statements in code.

The migrations for this generate fine, but the owned type primary key isn't recorded in the ModelSnapshot, so every time I generate a new migration, it attempts to rename the PK from PK_foo to pk_foo, even though it already is pk_foo in the database itself. This migration will obviously fail unless the offending line is removed.

Is there any way to override this? Or would the workaround be to make it not an owned entity?

This is the partial OnModelCreating code:

```
builder.Entity<Foo>()
    .OwnsOne(t => t.Bar)
    .ToTable("bar")
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

foreach (var entity in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    entity.Relational().TableName = entity.Relational().TableName.ToSnakeCase();

    foreach (var property in entity.GetProperties())
    {
        property.Relational().ColumnName = property.Name.ToSnakeCase();
    }

    foreach (var key in entity.GetKeys())
    {
        key.Relational().Name = key.Relational().Name.ToSnakeCase();
    }

    foreach (var key in entity.GetForeignKeys())
    {
        key.Relational().Name = key.Relational().Name.ToSnakeCase();
    }

    foreach (var index in entity.GetIndexes())
    {
        index.Relational().Name = index.Relational().Name.ToSnakeCase();
    }
}
```

This is the migration created:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "bar",
    columns: table => new
    {
        foo_id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
        data = table.Column<byte[]>(nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("pk_bar", x => x.foo_id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "fk_bar_foo_foo_id",
            column: x => x.foo_id,
            principalTable: "foo",
            principalColumn: "id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
});
```

This is the relevant part of the model snapshot

```
modelBuilder.Entity("ExampleProject.Foo", b =>
{
    b.OwnsOne("ExampleProject.Bar", "Bar", b1 =>
        {
            b1.Property<int>("FooId")
                .HasColumnName("foo_id");

            b1.Property<byte[]>("Data")
                .HasColumnName("data");

            b1.ToTable("bar");

            b1.HasOne("ExampleProject.Foo")
                .WithOne("Bar")
                .HasForeignKey("ExampleProject.Bar", "FooId")
                .HasConstraintName("fk_bar_foo_foo_id")
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        });
});
```

EF Core version: 2.0
Database Provider: Npgsql
Operating system: Windows 10
IDE: Visual Studio 2017 15.3.4

Comment: You can use `Column` DataAnnotations on PK.

Comment: As this is an owned entity, there is no PK in the code. The Bar entity is simply


    "public class Bar
    {
        public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    }"

Comment: Can you try `[Column("pk_foo")]`
`PK_foo`

Comment: yep - added a TitleId property and added the pk_foo, but the primary key still was not being generated correctly.

Comment: What column name exactly u want?

Comment: the column name isn't the issue - everything in the database is being generated correctly. the problem is that it's not being stored in the database modelsnapshot, so when running a new migration it tries to rename the key from PK_title_image to pk_title_image, even though it's already called pk_title_image.

Comment: @Bonnotbh Same happens in EFC 2.0.2 with SqlServer, hence I'm assuming this is a common issue. Consider posting it to their issue tracker, I don't see any workaround so far.

Comment: suspected as much - posted it here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a workaround for this. I have added to the EF Core Issue Tracker [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11655). For now I have changed the Bar entity so it is now not an owned object of Foo.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Brice Lambson. There's no way to address the primary key name from the ModelBuilder API.

The only way I can see to configure it is to drop down to metadata:

```
b1.Metadata.DeclaringEntityType
    .GetOrSetPrimaryKey(b1.Property("FooId").Metadata)
    .Relational().Name = "pk_bar";
```

The issue has been added to [Backlog](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/milestone/2).